# Get firebase data snapshot with rxjava2

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm trying to get user score from Firebase database by using RxJava2. I'm not getting any error, logcat is clear. Any method of subscriber is not working (not showing text on logcat).

```
override fun getUserScore(){
        val query = scoreReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)

        rxfirebase(query).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe { object: Subscriber<DataSnapshot>{
            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.d("UserScoreComplete", "complete")
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription?) {
                Log.d("UserScoreSubscribe", "subscribe")
            }

            override fun onNext(t: DataSnapshot?) {
                val score = t?.getValue(Score::class.java)
                Log.d("UserScore", score?.score)
            }

            override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("UserScoreError", t.toString())
            }
        } }
        }


    override fun rxfirebase(ref: Query): Observable<DataSnapshot>{
        return Observable.create { emitter ->
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d("rxFirebase error", p0.message)
                    emitter.onError(p0.toException())
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    emitter.onNext(p0)
                    emitter.onComplete()
```